# Посдкажите плагин для публикации фото с imgur.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, изображения

Нужен плагин который позволяет указать соответствующий альбом c imgur.com для публикации фото на своем сайте. Желательно с разбивкой на страницы или с "lazy load".